# Trouble setting up django settings

Tags: django

I'm just learning Django and trying to setup the View and URLconfs (http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/).

Inside my project folder "mysite" (/Users/NAME/Desktop/development/Python/djcode/mysite), I have the following two files:

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

and urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

However, when I run the test server, it shows a 404 page saying:

> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ^hello/$
>
> The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

I think this has to do with my settings.py not being correct. What do I need to change in the settings.py file to point it to the correct destination?

Comment: And you call the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/?

Comment: ha, thank you. ('my computer isn't working'. 'did you press the on button?')

Comment: "> from mysite.views import hello"
Don't use project name. This is bad practice, because you can't use your application in other projects

Comment: "The current URL, ," This shows that django really does not get any path. your urlpattern should catch 127.0.0.1:8000/hello/

Comment: @Alerion -- could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'don't use project names'? What would be an example of a better way to phrase it.

Comment: @David542 `from views import hello` and add path to the project to PYTHON_PATH in settings, manage.py or wsgi script like this: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no urlconf pattern corresponding to the root of your webserver. Add `^$` and make it go somewhere.

Comment: It is if you want to have something in the root of the web server.

Comment: Yes, but we are talking about /hello/. In http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/ we can see: "so open up a Web browser and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL you entered when testing it was "http://localhost:8000/". You should enter "http://localhost:8000/hello/" to see the output of the function you made.